# jQuery switchClass() doesn't work with CSS :after selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ys54w/1/)

If you go to watch the jsfiddle demo and try it you can see the blue bordered div is go away as I want but the the text "Opened" won't changed to "Closed" in the switchClass().
(If I use other kind of css elements and not :after selector than the switchClass() is works fine)

HTML:

```
<div class="filter_title">
    <div class="filter_title_price" id="filter_price_toggle"><span>Price</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hideprice" style="margin-top:10px; border:1px solid blue;">If you click Price [Opened] I will go away :) but the text "Opened" won't change to text "Closed"</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#filter_price_toggle").click(function () {
        $(".hideprice").toggle("blind", 250);
        $("filter_title_price").switchClass("filter_title_price", "filter_title_price2", 250);
        $("filter_title_price2").switchClass("filter_title_price2", "filter_title_price", 250);
        return false;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.filter_title {
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    border-color: #fff #d9d9d9 #d9d9d9;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.filter_title_price:after {
    content:"[Opened]";
}
.filter_title_price2:after {
    content:"[Closed]";
}
```

How can I change the text?

Or the switchClass() and the css :after selector do not cooperate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is missing the `.` for the class selector and once toggled the class is toggling right back to the original.  The following example introduces a new class on the `div` to avoid conflicts and utilizes a conditional statement to determine how the CSS class should be toggled.

**HTML**

```
<div class="filter_title">
    <div class="hook filter_title_price" id="filter_price_toggle"><span>Price</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hideprice" style="margin-top:10px; border:1px solid blue;">If you click Price [Opened] I will go away :) but the text "Opened" won't change to text "Closed"</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#filter_price_toggle").click(function () {
        $(".hideprice").toggle("blind", 250);
        if($(".hook").hasClass("filter_title_price")){
            $(".hook").switchClass("filter_title_price", "filter_title_price2", 250);
        }else{
            $(".hook").switchClass("filter_title_price2", "filter_title_price", 250);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ys54w/9/

Comment: @Gery happens to all of us.  I can see how you go there since you used the switchClass function right after it which doesn't require the `.`

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking whether that class exist in dom or not.and you are directly firing 2 switch class events.that way it wont work.

you need to check that what class exist first and do switchclass accordingly.

```
    if($(this).attr("class")=="filter_title_price")
    $(this).switchClass("filter_title_price", "filter_title_price2", 250);
    else
    $(this).switchClass("filter_title_price2", "filter_title_price", 250);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bXuFc/)**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, couple of problems here.

- Firstly, your selector is wrong for the object you're running switchClass on. Since you're running it on what you clicked you can just use `$(this)`.
- Secondly, you're trying to switch and then you switch straight back again on every click. You need to only do the relevant `switchClass` on each click.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  $("#filter_price_toggle").click(function () {
    $(".hideprice").toggle("blind", 250);
    if ($(this).hasClass("filter_title_price"))
      $(this).switchClass("filter_title_price", "filter_title_price2", 250);
    else
      $(this).switchClass("filter_title_price2", "filter_title_price", 250);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $(function () {
       $("#filter_price_toggle").on('click', function () {
           var element = $(this);
           $(".hideprice").toggle("blind", 250);
           element.hasClass("filter_title_price") ? element.switchClass("filter_title_price", "filter_title_price2", 250) : element.switchClass("filter_title_price2", "filter_title_price", 250);
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("#filter_price_toggle").click(function () {
    $(".hideprice").toggle("blind", 250);
    if($(this).hasClass('filter_title_price'))
        $(".filter_title_price").switchClass("filter_title_price", "filter_title_price2", 250);
    else
        $(".filter_title_price2").switchClass("filter_title_price2", "filter_title_price", 250);
    return false;
});
});
```